# Is it possible to query Jetty Server for stats?

Tags: clojure, jetty

I am looking to send statistics like the number of requests being handled by the jetty server, the number of requests waiting in queue etc. I would like to periodically send this as a count to my statsd agent to be able to plot it on Grafana. But I could not find any public apis on the `Server` class that expose such metrics.
I am guessing there are other people who are already doing it. I would like to know if there is a standard way to fetch these metrics programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Jetty provides an API to collect and expose statistics - [`StatisticsHandler`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#statistics-handler). The handler can expose metrics via JMX but it doesn't have a built-in integration with StatsD.

In order to integrate it with StatsD manually, you could use one of the java statsd clients, e.g. [java-statsd-client](https://github.com/tim-group/java-statsd-client). For instance, you could schedule a task to read the data from the `StatisticsHandler` and send it to the StatsD agent using the abovementioned library.

Comment: nice! what would be the path for this handler? Where can I read about about it?

Comment: @Ashwin, if you click on the StatisticsHandler in the answer, it'll lead to the documentation page that describes its usage. The handler doesn't need to be registered on a specific path as every single request needs to go through that handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring boot actuator it should already gather metrics from jetty's http connection thread pool + Micrometer used by spring boot for metering already provides an [integration with StatsD](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/statsD). I believe it manually sets up the jetty's http connection pool so that it already exposes all the relevant metrics.

Otherwise you'll have to implement this feature "manually":

One possible implementation is using JMX to expose Connection thread pool statistics when you setup the jetty server.

The way to setup the JMX server can differ depending on how do use jetty. But in general I've found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406631/how-to-collect-and-get-connection-pool-statistics-using-jetty-and-spring-boot) that talks about the monitoring pool of jetty.

Then you could read these values from JMX MBean and integrate with stats.d agent. One possible way of such an integration might be [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans). Disclaimer: I've never used it by myself so can't say nothing about it.

Comment: unfortunately I am not using springboot:( I am using jetty server with Clojure

Comment: Ah, ok, in this case probably the second part of my answer might be relevant?